# Why doesn't java.util.Calendar make use of Enums?

Tags: java, datetime, enums, calendar

I sometimes get frustrated by the lack of type safety with j.u.Calendar and wondered if there was a *good* reason for not using enums in the Calendar API that has gone over my head, or if the only reason is that it was probably written before enums were a part of the language and is not worth breaking old code.

A secondary sub-question is: Is it worth my time to create a more type safe wrapper around the Calendar class or has this been done before?

---

**Summary:** `Calendar` has been around since Java 1.1 whereas `Enums` only made it in Java 5, [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is considered the best replacement package for `Calendar`.

Comment: Hopefully Java 7 will update time and date processing through JSR-310 (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php). The lead on this is Stephen Colebourne who is one of the guys behind joda time.

Comment: @Qwerky: It is not in the list on http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/, and [JSR 336](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336) lists it as **deferred to future Java SE releases**. It is likely to be included in Java SE 8 ([JSR 337](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums weren't part of Java when Calendar was written.  They haven't been added due to neglect, fear of breaking backward compatibility, insufficient priority, developers who don't agree with you - take your pick.

Answer (score 6):

It was implemented before enums made their way into the language (enums arrived at version 5).

[JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is widely considered the best replacement package.

Comment: JODA Time doesn't seem to use enums either, instead using static const int.

Answer (score 2):

The `Calendar` class has been around since Java 1.1, which is why it doesn't use `Enums`.

I strongly recommend using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) rather than the train-wreck that is `java.util.Calendar`.